# Sequential exexcute javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to calculate the total euros of my coins ? 
When all variables are calculated then calculate total value.
How to do this in sequential order ?
I already tried to put in a while loop but I get endless loop.

```js
var Bytecoin = 0;
var IOTA = 0;
var Stellar = 0;
var Steem = 0;
var Cardano = 0;
var Total = 0;

$.getJSON('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/372/?convert=EUR', function(data) {
  Bytecoin = 0.28399 * data.data.quotes.EUR.price;
  $(".mypanel1a").html(data.data.name + ":");
  $(".mypanel1").html(Bytecoin.toFixed(2) + " €");
});

$.getJSON('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1720/?convert=EUR', function(data) {
  IOTA = 0.446 * data.data.quotes.EUR.price;
  $(".mypanel2a").html(data.data.name + ":");
  $(".mypanel2").html(IOTA.toFixed(2) + " €");
});

$.getJSON('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/512/?convert=EUR', function(data) {
  Stellar = 0.94 * data.data.quotes.EUR.price;
  $(".mypanel3a").html(data.data.name + ":");
  $(".mypanel3").html(Stellar.toFixed(2) + " €");
});

$.getJSON('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1230/?convert=EUR', function(data) {
  Steem = 0.751 * data.data.quotes.EUR.price;
  $(".mypanel4a").html(data.data.name + ":");
  $(".mypanel4").html(Steem.toFixed(2) + " €");
});

$.getJSON('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/2010/?convert=EUR', function(data) {
  Cardano = 0.935 * data.data.quotes.EUR.price;
  $(".mypanel5a").html(data.data.name + ":");
  $(".mypanel5").html(Cardano.toFixed(2) + " €");
});

Total = Bytecoin + IOTA + Stellar + Steem + Cardano;

$(".mypanel6").html(Total.toFixed(2) + " €");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <table id='mytab' align="center" width="10%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2">
    <tr>
      <td align="right" class="mypanel1a"></td>
      <td align="right" class="mypanel1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right" class="mypanel2a"></td>
      <td align="right" class="mypanel2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right" class="mypanel3a"></td>
      <td align="right" class="mypanel3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right" class="mypanel4a"></td>
      <td align="right" class="mypanel4"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right" class="mypanel5a"></td>
      <td align="right" class="mypanel5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Total: </td>
      <td align="right" class="mypanel6"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: What is $? Are you using jQuery, an alternative is using the "jQuery" keyword instead of $

Comment: hugo, read about getJSON ... it returns a *Promise* ... *promises* can be *chained* so you can do "sequential order" quite easily ... so `$.getJSON(......).then(() => $.getJSON(......))` .... and so on

Comment: When you run the snippet is says $ is undefined, this is what I was checking

Comment: I have updated it (jQuery needed to be imported). It's now working.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`$.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) to wait for all calls to resolve before actually calculating the sum:

```js
var Bytecoin = 0;
var IOTA = 0;
var Stellar = 0;
var Steem = 0;
var Cardano = 0;
var Total = 0;

var callback = function() {
  Total = Bytecoin + IOTA + Stellar + Steem + Cardano;

  $(".mypanel6").html(Total.toFixed(2) + " €");
};

$.when(

  $.getJSON('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/372/?convert=EUR', function(data) {
    Bytecoin = 0.28399 * data.data.quotes.EUR.price;
    $(".mypanel1a").html(data.data.name + ":");
    $(".mypanel1").html(Bytecoin.toFixed(2) + " €");
  }),
  
  $.getJSON('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1720/?convert=EUR', function(data) {
    IOTA = 0.446 * data.data.quotes.EUR.price;
    $(".mypanel2a").html(data.data.name + ":");
    $(".mypanel2").html(IOTA.toFixed(2) + " €");
  }),
  
  $.getJSON('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/512/?convert=EUR', function(data) {
    Stellar = 0.94 * data.data.quotes.EUR.price;
    $(".mypanel3a").html(data.data.name + ":");
    $(".mypanel3").html(Stellar.toFixed(2) + " €");
  }),
  
  $.getJSON('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1230/?convert=EUR', function(data) {
    Steem = 0.751 * data.data.quotes.EUR.price;
    $(".mypanel4a").html(data.data.name + ":");
    $(".mypanel4").html(Steem.toFixed(2) + " €");
  }),
  
  $.getJSON('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/2010/?convert=EUR', function(data) {
    Cardano = 0.935 * data.data.quotes.EUR.price;
    $(".mypanel5a").html(data.data.name + ":");
    $(".mypanel5").html(Cardano.toFixed(2) + " €");
  })
  
).then(callback);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <table id='mytab' align="center" width="10%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2">
    <tr>
      <td align="right" class="mypanel1a"></td>
      <td align="right" class="mypanel1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right" class="mypanel2a"></td>
      <td align="right" class="mypanel2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right" class="mypanel3a"></td>
      <td align="right" class="mypanel3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right" class="mypanel4a"></td>
      <td align="right" class="mypanel4"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right" class="mypanel5a"></td>
      <td align="right" class="mypanel5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Total: </td>
      <td align="right" class="mypanel6"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much all for your help !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in sequence (like you said in the quetion) rather than all at once - the fact that jQuery AJAX methods return a Promise is useful

```
$.getJSON('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/372/?convert=EUR')
.then(function(data) {
    Bytecoin = 0.28399 * data.data.quotes.EUR.price;
    $(".mypanel1a").html(data.data.name + ":");
    $(".mypanel1").html(Bytecoin.toFixed(2) + " €");
    return $.getJSON('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1720/?convert=EUR');
})
.then(function(data) {
  IOTA = 0.446 * data.data.quotes.EUR.price;
  $(".mypanel2a").html(data.data.name + ":");
  $(".mypanel2").html(IOTA.toFixed(2) + " €");
  return $.getJSON('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/512/?convert=EUR');
})
.then ... etc
```

However, if the only "sequential" part you are having an issue with is the "Total", then I would recommend a very different approach - DRY - "Don't Repeat Yourself" - as you can see, in each request the code is almost identical ... so, make it a function instead

```
const getTicker = ([ticker, mult, index]) => $.getJSON(`https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/${ticker}/?convert=EUR`).then(data => {
    const v = mult * data.data.quotes.EUR.price;
    $(`.mypanel${index}a`).html(data.data.name + ":");
    $(`.mypanel${index}`).html(v.toFixed(2) + " €");
    return v;
});
```

then make an array of ticker/multiplier/indexes

```
const tickers = [
    [372, 0.28399, 1],
    [1720, 0.446, 2],
    [512, 0.94, 3],
    [1230, 0.751, 4],
    [2010, 0.935, 5]
];
```

then only 3 more lines of code will do the work

```
Promise.all(tickers.map(item => getTicker(item)))
.then(prices => prices.reduce((a, b) => a + b))
.then(total => $(".mypanel6").html(total.toFixed(2) + " €"));
```

or, if you insist on using `$.when` - that last 3 lines can be

```
$.when(...tickers.map(item => getTicker(item)))
.then((...prices) => prices.reduce((a, b) => a + b))
.then(total => $(".mypanel6").html(total.toFixed(2) + " €"));
```

---

And finally - without jQuery

```js
const getTicker = ([ticker, mult, index]) => fetch(`https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/${ticker}/?convert=EUR`)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
    const v = mult * data.data.quotes.EUR.price;
    document.querySelector(`.mypanel${index}a`).innerHTML = data.data.name + ":";
    document.querySelector(`.mypanel${index}`).innerHTML = v.toFixed(2) + " €";
    return v;
});

const tickers = [
    [372, 0.28399, 1],
    [1720, 0.446, 2],
    [512, 0.94, 3],
    [1230, 0.751, 4],
    [2010, 0.935, 5]
];

Promise.all(tickers.map(item => getTicker(item)))
.then(prices => prices.reduce((a, b) => a + b))
.then(total => document.querySelector(".mypanel6").innerHTML = total.toFixed(2) + " €");
```

```html
  <table id='mytab' align="center" width="50%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2">
    <tr>
      <td align="right" class="mypanel1a"></td>
      <td align="right" class="mypanel1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right" class="mypanel2a"></td>
      <td align="right" class="mypanel2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right" class="mypanel3a"></td>
      <td align="right" class="mypanel3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right" class="mypanel4a"></td>
      <td align="right" class="mypanel4"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right" class="mypanel5a"></td>
      <td align="right" class="mypanel5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Total: </td>
      <td align="right" class="mypanel6"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

---

And how I would do it to be "flexible"

```js
const getTicker = el => {
    const {mult, ticker} = el.dataset;
    
    return fetch(`https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/${ticker}/?convert=EUR`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        const v = mult * data.data.quotes.EUR.price;
        el.querySelector('td:first-child').innerHTML = data.data.name + ":";
        el.querySelector('td:last-child').innerHTML = v.toFixed(2) + " €";
        return v;
    });
};
const tickers = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.ticker'));
Promise.all(tickers.map(item => getTicker(item)))
.then(prices => prices.reduce((a, b) => a + b))
.then(total => document.querySelector(".total").innerHTML = total.toFixed(2) + " €");
```

```html
  <table id='mytab' align="center" width="50%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2">
    <tr data-ticker='372' data-mult='0.28399' class='ticker'>
      <td align="right"></td>
      <td align="right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-ticker='1720' data-mult='0.446' class='ticker'>
      <td align="right"></td>
      <td align="right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-ticker='512' data-mult='0.94' class='ticker'>
      <td align="right"></td>
      <td align="right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-ticker='1230' data-mult='0.751' class='ticker'>
      <td align="right"></td>
      <td align="right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-ticker='2010' data-mult='0.935' class='ticker'>
      <td align="right"></td>
      <td align="right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Total: </td>
      <td align="right" class="total"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Although, thinking about it, I'd probably just create the rows dynamically, but then you'd have to realise the order may be different depending on the responses

Comment: Thank you very much all for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You just need wrapped them all inside a promise and wait for all cryptocurrency value to fetch.

```
var Bytecoin = 0;
var IOTA = 0;
var Stellar = 0;
var Steem = 0;
var Cardano = 0;
var Total = 0;

var req1 = $.getJSON('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/372/?convert=EUR', 
function(data) 
{
 Bytecoin = 0.28399 * data.data.quotes.EUR.price;
 $(".mypanel1a").html(data.data.name + ":");
 $(".mypanel1").html(Bytecoin.toFixed(2) + " €");
});

var req2 = $.getJSON('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1720/?convert=EUR', 
 function(data) {
 IOTA = 0.446 * data.data.quotes.EUR.price;
 $(".mypanel2a").html(data.data.name + ":");
 $(".mypanel2").html(IOTA.toFixed(2) + " €");
});

var req3 = $.getJSON('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/512/?convert=EUR', 
function(data) {
  Stellar = 0.94 * data.data.quotes.EUR.price;
  $(".mypanel3a").html(data.data.name + ":");
  $(".mypanel3").html(Stellar.toFixed(2) + " €");
 });

var req4 = $.getJSON('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1230/?convert=EUR', 
function(data) {
 Steem = 0.751 * data.data.quotes.EUR.price;
 $(".mypanel4a").html(data.data.name + ":");
 $(".mypanel4").html(Steem.toFixed(2) + " €");
});

var req5 = $.getJSON('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/2010/?convert=EUR', 
function(data) {
  Cardano = 0.935 * data.data.quotes.EUR.price;
  $(".mypanel5a").html(data.data.name + ":");
  $(".mypanel5").html(Cardano.toFixed(2) + " €");
});

Promise.all([req1,req2,req3,req4,req5]).then((res) => {
 Total = Bytecoin + IOTA + Stellar + Steem + Cardano;

 $(".mypanel6").html(Total.toFixed(2) + " €");
```

});